# How do I create dynamic parallel arrays that read from an excel file? c#

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, io

I am trying to read a specific row of data into an array and another row (Row A) into its own array. I know how to get my excel file to read but i do not know how to get a specific row into an array....Please help me understand how to **declare two dynamic parallel arrays!**

```
  //Checks if the ID Number Matches
            string value = EmployeeIDTextbox.Text;
            Match match = Regex.Match(value, @".*[0-9].*");
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            int TotalRows = xlsDs.Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < TotalRows; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = xlsDs.Rows[i];

                //Cell Name that contains ID Number
                String row_Val = row["Enter Employee ID number"].ToString(); 

                Match myMatch = Regex.Match(row_Val, EmployeeIDTextbox.Text);

                //If ID Number is found
                if (match.Success && myMatch.Success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(EmployeeIDTextbox);

                    //Place Employee information in array

                    //Places Coloumn headers in array
```

Comment: Use 2 lists & convert to array after (if necessary)

Comment: @PaulF how would I declare the list?

Comment: Depends on data type but List<String> list1 = new List<String>(); Then l1.Add( ...); to add to the list & finally l1.ToArray() if you need to convert to array.

Comment: @PaulF for list1.Add()... what I am not sure what to put in the parenthesis...the row contains all numbers. I tried to put "row" in the parenthesis but it did not work

Comment: What information do you need to store? If just the ID number then l1.Add(row_Val). If you want to store the entire row then have a list of DataRows - List<DataRow> then l1.Add(row) should work. If a subset of the data then consider extracting it to a separate class & storing it in the list. The specific solution depends on your requirements - but a list can be treated as a "dynamic array" which is what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can already access row values as an array like this:

```
var rowValues = row.ItemArray;
```

Column headers can be converted into an array like this:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
....
var columnHeaders = table.Columns
    .Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Select(x => x.ColumnName)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: when I try to Output the array Console.WriteLine(rowValues); The console just shows System.Object[]

Comment: The console does not support outputting an array directly (except in the manner you just observed).  You need to loop over each element manually, or convert the array into a string by using something like the String.Join method.